# MySQL php array issue

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

what i am attempting to build is an array from a database query in php mysql. loop through that array looking for a certain string with strpos.

when the register page loads, i include a file, this file source is below:

```
mysql_select_db($database_connBlog, $connBlog);
$query_rsBannedDomains = "SELECT * FROM banned_emailproviders";
$rsBannedDomains = mysql_query($query_rsBannedDomains, $connBlog) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rsBannedDomains = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsBannedDomains);
$totalRows_rsBannedDomains = mysql_num_rows($rsBannedDomains);


$bannedArray = array(); 
    do {
    array_push($bannedArray, $row_rsBannedDomains['domain_emailprovider']);
    }
    while ($row_rsBannedDomains = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsBannedDomains));

//print_r($bannedArray);

$emailaddress = $_POST['email_usr'];

foreach($bannedArray as $key => $domain){
    if(strpos($emailaddress, $domain) == false){
        echo (strpos($emailaddress, $domain));
    } else {
        header ("Location: http://www.disney.com");

    }
}
```

When the register page is submitted, it is submitted to itself. The include to the source above, is the second line in the register php file. the first line is the include for the database connection.

The odd thing is this works sometimes when I click back and re submit the form.

Comment: do...while isn't a good way to loop over DB results, because it will always run through the loop at least once, and it is possible a query will return 0 rows.  use while instead.

Comment: Too add to GordonM's comment, you should remove that `$row_rsBannedDomains = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsBannedDomains);
` first line at the top.  Also, `array_push()` isn't really necessary here.  Looks like you can just do `$bannedArray[] = $row_rsBannedDomains['domain_emailprovider'];` in that `while` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to load the whole table and then loop through it with PHP.  In fact this is a very inefficient way of doing it.  Just query the database to see if the domain part of the email address is one of the entries in the table instead.

```
$emailaddress = substr ($_POST['email_usr'], strpos ($emailaddress = $_POST['email_usr'];
, '@'));

$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS banned FROM banned_emailproviders WHERE domain_emailprovider = '" . mysql_real_escape_string ($emailaddress) . "'"
if (($res = mysql_query ($query)) && ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($res)) && ($row ['banned'] > 0))
{
    // The domain was in the banned list
}
else
if (!$res)
{
    // Something went wrong querying the database
    die (mysql_error ());
}
else
{
    // The domain wasn't in the banned list
}
```

Please note the above code hasn't been tested so it might need some tweaking to work properly.

Comment: thank you for the idea. i used this and was able to accomplish what i was after. good logic here.

Comment: i am still having a very dum occurance to where this only works if you submit the form, click back on the browser and submit the form again. for some reason, even though the form is submitting to itself, that it is running the code in sequence, until the second submit which makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I see is

```
if(strpos($emailaddress, $domain) == false){
```

should be

```
if(strpos($emailaddress, $domain) === false){
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: i did change that with the same result. some browsers after clicking back and resubmitting will catch the header if statements on known banned emails.